# Help with creating color tinted glass with dusty look

Tags: color, glass

I'm creating a mars scene and have a glass pane on the roof of a building. I want to give it a better look than just clear or straight one color. I would like to make add a orange reflective tint to it and make it look almost as if it were dusty with Martian sand.

Comment: Could you post reference image of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this any good?
[image: Orange metallic glass]

The trick is to *mix* between a transparent shader and a glossy shader. First, you'll need a dust texture. I used this one from Blender Guru.

[image: Dust Texture]
I set up a mapping and coordinate nodes just to be professional, as it gives you more control over the texture. Next, add it to an inverted math texture node (I chose noise, as I think it gives the best result), then color ramp it as you wish to an orange shade. At this point, we need to make our object behave like both a metal *and* glass, so I use a transparent node mixed with a glossy node, both with color from the color ramp.
The final node setup looks like this:
[image: Node Setup]

You can tinker with the amount of dust, metallic-ness, and transparency to your liking, but importantly, this material has all of those things.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you very much for the help.